# DNS_GET_RECORD Failing with Register.com Domains

Tags: php, dns

I am using a PHP script using dns_get_record (with DNS_ANY) and it is working fine but, is throwing an error on any domain registered with Register.com.

```
Warning: dns_get_record() [function.dns-get-record]: res_nsend() failed in...
```

Any ideas on why this would be?  Anyone else had this issue?

**EDIT:**

Been doing some research and it looks like [this](http://social.technet.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/exchangesvrtransport/thread/3ad694bd-6ce7-4e27-a9f9-890ceb1ee936) may be related.  Register.com's servers appear to have issues with IPv6.

Still would love to know if anyone else has had this issue.

Comment: please show a complete example of the smallest possible PHP program which exhibits this behaviour, with a real domain name in it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe it fails on the PTR record, not 100% sure but try this and see if it works.

```
$dns_record = dns_get_record("somedomain.com", DNS_ALL - DNS_PTR);
var_dump($dns_record);
```